# Copy multiple files with control

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to copy multiple files in one directory and copy and rename the file in increments of 500. For example the first 500 files in C:\Pics (with random original names) will be renamed 500-1000 and the new directory they are placed in is called 500…….files 1000-1500 would go into directory 1000 and so on.

The current code does not rename the files put instead puts it in a new directory with the correct number.  This was just a start. I believe the code below Is a good start can anyone help me modify to get the results desired?

```
import os, glob

target = 'C:\Pics'
prefix = 'p0'        
os.chdir(target)
allfiles = os.listdir(target)        
count = 500
for filename in allfiles:
    if not glob.glob('*.jpg'): continue
    dirname = prefix + str(count)
    target = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
    os.renames(filename, target)
    count +=1
```

Answer (score 2):

os.listdir and glob.glob are similar functions.  They both return lists of files/dirs, so they don't belong in the same loop (at least not the way you're trying to use them).  The main difference is that os.listdir just takes a directory and returns basically `*.*` from it (minus . and ..), where as glob.glob expects a "globbing pattern" which can contain `*` `?` `[]` in a restricted regex format.  The function you might be thinking of here (instead of glob.glob) is fnmatch.fnmatch, which applies a globbing pattern to a single file name.

> os.**listdir**(path)
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory
>   given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the
>   special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the
>   directory.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows.
>
> Changed in version 2.3: On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if path is a Unicode object, the result > will be a list of Unicode objects. Undecodable filenames will still be returned as string
>   objects.
>
> glob.**glob**(pathname)
>
> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that
>   match pathname, which must be a string containing a path
>   specification. pathname can be either absolute (like
>   /usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile) or relative (like ../../Tools/*/*.gif),
>   and can contain shell-style wildcards. Broken symlinks are included in
>   the results (as in the shell).

Sorry, too lazy to actually mock up files and test this, but then I'd be doing all the work for you.  But this should work (or be a darn close to what I think you're aiming at). ;)

```
import os
import fnmatch
import os.path

target = 'C:\Pics'
os.chdir(target)
allfiles = os.listdir(target)
count = 500
for filename in allfiles:
    if not fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.jpg'):
        continue
    if count % 500 == 0:
        dirname = 'p%04d' % count
        if not os.path.exists(dirname):
            os.mkdir(dirname)
    target = os.path.join(dirname, '%d.jpg' % count)
    os.rename(filename, target)
    count += 1
```

Comment: +1, yours is more complete, deleting mine so as not to clutter the question.